# is it better to redirect output at each iteration or at the end

Tags: bash

I'm curios which one is better and more optimized:

Suppose this `while` loop:

```
while read -r user_id
do
    command user "$user_id" | grep user_name | awk '{print $4}' | head -1
    command user "$user_id" | grep -oE "user_id='[0-9a-z]{24}'"
done < all_user_ids
```

Which one is better:

One:

```
while read -r user_id
do
    command user "$user_id" | grep user_name | awk '{print $4}' | head -1
    command user "$user_id" | grep -oE "user_id='[0-9a-z]{24}'"
done < all_user_ids > user_names_and_user_ids
```

Two:

```
rm -f user_names_and_user_ids # to ensure file is removed and data is new
while read -r user_id
do
    command user "$user_id" | grep user_name | awk '{print $4}' | head -1 >> user_names_and_user_ids
    command user "$user_id" | grep -oE "user_id='[0-9a-z]{24}'" >> user_names_and_user_ids
done < all_user_ids
```

As I think and up to my knowledge, in the first one, data is written in the RAM and after each iteration, data is getting bigger (first is two lines, then four, then six, etc.), so after each iteration the memory should memorize (or a word like this) the last output and obtain the whole new output. So the memory usage increases.

But in the second one, at each iteration the only thing RAM memorizes is that command to write to output and then it's clear.

I also think a better way is to have all the data in a file like this, then iterate over that file (I think that may be faster):

```
while read -r user_id
do
    command user "$user_id" > all_user_data
done < all_user_ids # > all_user_data # or even here
```

Then iterate over the `all_user_data`.

Which one is better in `bash`?

Comment: Not a full answer but, if performance is one of your concerns, using just one `awk` script to do all your filtering, instead of running the same `command user "$user_id"` twice, plus two `grep`, one `awk` and one `head`, is probably something to consider.

Comment: Reopening the file every time you want to write to it isn't going to be fast. If speed is what you need, benchmark. If you can't benchmark any difference, don't bother.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that each child process flushes stdout at the end of execution, so I don't expect much difference with respect to buffering. Actually, your 4-stage pipe itself performs so badly, that I would not start optimizing that instead of worrying about buffer issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is almost always better.

Neither one buffers the output to RAM; in all cases, the final command in each pipeline (`head -1` and `grep -eO ...`) writes directly to the file. The commands themselves probably buffer their input and output, but only small amounts, it's done to speed them up, and it'll be the same in both versions.

The only real difference is that the second wastes some time opening and closing the file a lot.

If you're worried about performance, there are much more important things to look at. Often, the biggest thing that takes time in a shell script is forking subprocesses to run external commands. Therefore, if performance is a concern (e.g. in a loop you're going to run many times), you should minimize the number of external commands. So, for example, replace `grep user_name | awk '{print $4}' | head -1` with `awk '/user_name/ {print $4; exit}'`.

As Renaud Pacalet said in a comment, it'd also be better to avoid running the `command user "$user_id"` command twice per iteration. The best method would be to replace both pipelines with a single `awk` command (awk is pretty powerful). If that's not possible for some reason, you could store the command's output in a file (or if it's not too big, a variable), and then feed that single output through the rest of both pipelines.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, but I think that in the `one`, the birth of file changes at each iteration and also in the first iteration result is `this is first` and written to file, then in the second iteration, the result is `this is first, this is second` and all of them are in memory and they get bigger. But in the `second`, each iteration only contains `this is ...` with less bytes and characters. Isn't that true?

Comment: @Saeed No, that's not how it works at all. The birth of the file does not change each iteration (in either version). Also, in both versions, each iteration's result is written to the file and *not* retained in memory or rewritten by later iterations. So in your example, the first iteration would write `this is first` into the file, then the second iteration would just add `this is second` after it (without needing to rewrite what the first iteration had written).

Answer (score 1):

I think second one is better,the output is directly appended to the file `user_names_and_user_ids` using the `>>` redirect operator and this idea reduces memory usage, because the output is immediately written to the file instead of being stored in memory, so it can be more efficient, especially if you have a large number of iterations!

and you can also consider optimizing the commands within the loop,instead of calling `command user "$user_id"` twice, you can store the result in a variable and then use that variable for both `grep` and `awk` commands, with this way, you avoid executing the same command multiple times!

something like this:

```
rm -f user_names_and_user_ids #to check file is removed and data is new
while read -r user_id
do
    result=$(command user "$user_id")
    echo "$result" | grep user_name | awk '{print $4}' >> user_names_and_user_ids
    echo "$result" | grep -oE "user_id='[0-9a-z]{24}'" >> user_names_and_user_ids
done < all_user_ids
```

and as you see,it reduces the number of command executions and can improve performance, especially if the `command user "$user_id"` is resource intensive!

good luck !

Comment: This is incorrect, the first version does not do any additional buffering or use additional memory. In both versions, the commands write directly into the files. Try a test: open to terminal windows, and in one run `for ((i=1; i<=20; i++)); do sleep 1; echo "$i"; done >test.out` and while that's going run `tail -f test.out` in the other. You'll see the numbers written into the file one per second (as the `echo` commands execute), *not* buffered and written in one big batch at the end. (But you're entirely right about reducing commands inside the loop.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson thnx for pointing out the mistake in my answer,the first version does not accumulate the output in memory, but rather writes it directly to the file just like the second version.therefore, both versions have similar memory usage and optimization and I think the choice between them would depend on other factors such as readability,maintainability,and specific requirements of the script!

Comment: @Freeman thanks buddy for noting that I should use the command once and store it, then process that with commands like `echo ... | ...` in your answer. It also reduced the time too:)